# javascript: how to stop the page from reloading?

Tags: javascript, reload, onchange

I just wrote a small program which takes the input from user and shows the factorial table. Here is the code:

```
<h1>Table of factorials</h1>
<h3>Enter the number:<h3>
<form name="form1">
    <input type="text" name="num" onchange="display(parseInt(document.form1.num.value))"/>
    <input type="button" />
</form>
<script>
    function factorial(n){
        if(n<=1) return n;
        else return n*factorial(n-1);
    }
    function display(x){
        document.write("<table>");
        document.write("<tr><th>n</th><th>n!</th></tr>");
        for(var i =1;i<=x;i++){
            document.write("<tr><td>"+i+"</td><td>"+factorial(i)+"</td></tr>");
        }
        document.write("</table>");
        document.write("Generated at"+ new Date());
    }


</script>
```

But the problem is the form reloads again immediately after showing the table.
But if i use the button to trigger the function by `onclick="display(parseInt(document.form1.num.value))"` it does fine.
  How to fix this?
**EDIT:** Just noticed that it works fine in firefox too. The problem is with chrome, opera and safari

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d2DqP/7/ I tried in chrome, it just work fine.

Comment: for me it shows the table and then goes back to the form again in your jsfiddle too :(..i want it to stop on the table

Comment: Is the reload caused by a form submit event?

Comment: but there is no submit event in the form

Comment: @unussunu there is a input type button which on some browsers has the default action to submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prevent the default action of the input button. You can do this by JQuery's `preventDefault()`
function .Or just `<form onsubmit="return false;"> ... </form>`

Answer (score 4):

Use `<form onsubmit="return false;"> ... </form>`

Answer (score 0):

It's the problem of `document.write`, have a look at [what it means](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.write)