# How to change controller method that JSP page will not refresh after POST method. Spring MVC, AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jsp, post

> Here i have got AJAX script and i need to correct my controller

I need to do that when I'll send data to my controller from the form it will not refresh my page.
I have got a `<form>` at my JSP page and AJAX `<script>` that transfer my data from `<textarea>` to controller method, but it refreshing my page. How to do that my POST method will work without refreshing page? Thanx!

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="message" action="/app/user/messages/${iddialog}"
                        accept-charset="utf-8" ng-app="vandh" ng-controller="validateCtrl"
                        name="messageForm" novalidation="true">

<form:textarea path="text" class="form-control" rows="1" name="message"
                            id="message" ng-model="message" required="true"></form:textarea>
                        <div style="color: black"
                            ng-show="messageForm.message.$dirty && messageForm.message.$invalid">
                            <span ng-show="messageForm.message.$error.required"><spring:message
                                code="label.entermessage" /></span>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" id="addMessage" name="addMessage"><spring:message
                                code="label.sendmessage"/></button>
                        </div>

</form:form>

<script>
$("#addMessage").click(function() { 
    var text = $('#message').val();
    $.ajax({ 
    type : "POST", 
    url: "/app/user/messages/${iddialog}" , 
    async : false, 
    data : { 
    text : text 
    } 
    }); 

    });
</script>
```

Here is my controller method for POST method. Here i'm checking my message and adding it to database.

```
public void sendMessage(int iddialog, String text, String messender) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    // get current date time with Date()
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
    dialog.setIddialog(iddialog);
    Message mess = new Message();
    mess.setText(text);
    mess.setDialog(dialog);
    mess.setDate(dateFormat.format(date));
    mess.setMessender(messender);
    this.messageService.addMessage(mess);
    this.dialogService.updateUnreadMessInfo(iddialog, messender);
}

public boolean checkingMessage(String text) {
    if (text.contains("<") || text.contains(">") || text.contains("script") || text.contains("$")) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/messages/{iddialog}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String messages(@ModelAttribute("message") Message message, @RequestParam(value = "text") String text,
        @PathVariable(value = "iddialog") int iddialog, Model model, Principal principal) {
    System.out.println("ITS HERE");
    if (checkingMessage(text) != true) {
        sendMessage(iddialog, text, principal.getName());

        System.out.println("message sent!");
        // return "redirect:/user/messages/"+iddialog;
        return "messagesWithUser";
    } else {
        return "redirect:/user/messages";
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript: how to stop the page from reloading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937289/javascript-how-to-stop-the-page-from-reloading)

Comment: @kryger, no. in my case problem in controller. not in script

Answer (score 0):

I the above example when you are pressing #addMessage button two things are happening

1. Form submits (Thats why page relodes)
2. Ajax calling takes place

So to avoid reloading change the action of the form to `action="javascript:void(0);"`

So you need to change your controller according to Ajax call,because you are using Ajax to send that message.

Comment: I know that i need to change my controller! I tried it, but no success!
Look at my button, it has no submit type.
`<button class="btn btn-success" id="addMessage" name="addMessage"><spring:message
                                code="label.sendmessage"/></button>`

Comment: have you found out yet?

Comment: I did posting without refreshing page but it doesn't take my text from the form. it sending an empty message.